# Symfony 2, Doctrine 2 Multiple one to one relations from one entity to another

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I once more need help from you. 
Is it possible to implement more than one oneToOne relationship to another Entity?

I have a Entity called Route:
In this Entity I have a start-variable and a end-variable. I want that both of them 
are an oneToOne instance of my second Entity called Position.

Entity Position:
In here I have an ID, name, latitude and a longitude.

This picture shows it better:
http://s14.directupload.net/images/140324/36o8vyxm.jpg

Is that possible, and how would I implement this in Doctrine?
I´ve tried to to give both, start and end, an oneToOne Annotion, but doctrine won´t notice any changes.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the fields; What the problems?

In Route entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Position", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="start_position_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $answerRight;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Position", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="end_position_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $answerWrong;
```

And in Position entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Route")
 */
 private $route;
```

Comment: It is that simple ^^
I did the first step, but i forget the annonation in my route entity..

Thank you very much